# Criterion of nonsingular varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, differential-forms

It's well-known fact, that if $X$ is non-singular algebraic variety over algebraically closed field $k$ and $Y \subset X$ is its irreducible closed subscheme defined by sheaf of ideals $J$, then $Y$ is non-singular iff $\Omega_{Y/k}^1$ is locally free and the sequence $$0 \to J/J^2 \to \Omega_{X/k}^1\otimes \mathcal O_Y \to \Omega_{Y/k}^1 \to 0
$$ is exact.
I want to find examples when one of these conditions is not sufficient (neither implies the other). I think that there should be such affine examples, but I have no idea how can I construct it.

Comment: Is $Y$ reduced ?

Comment: @Cantlog No, it isn't. Y is subscheme, not subset as I read before)

Comment: If $k$ has characteristic $p>0$, consider $X$ the affine line and $Y$ defined by $t^p=0$. Then $\Omega^1_{Y/k}$ is free of rank $1$ on $O_Y$, but $Y$ is singular. I believe that $\Omega^1_{Y/k}$ locally free implies that $Y$ is non-singular. The example with $Y$ defined by $t^n=0$, $n$ prime to the characteristic of $k$ shows that the exactness does not implies non-singularity. Note that the exactness holds for lot of hypersurfaces $Y$ in any $X$.